# How do I recover a deleted customer from Magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, recovery

A customer was accidentally deleted from our Magento store (version 1.3.2). I'd like to restore just his information, if possible. Can I do it via SQL queries or should I go through Magento?

I have my backup database running another Magento store, so I believe I can create an export profile and limit it to only those customer records matching his email, then import that data to the live site. One hangup is that this will give him a new ID and the new ID won't be tied to the sales history. If all I have to do is update his ID to the old one or update the old sales to the new ID that's not a big deal, but I'm afraid I'm missing other things. Any ideas?

**Update**

I ended up exporting the single record from the backup server and importing it to the live site (via Magento > System > Import/Export > Profiles). Then in MySQL I updated customer_entity, setting the newly created ID back to the old one (I only updated the single table, it should do the rest of the work on the _int, _varchar, etc tables automatically). Result: customer is restored, addresses are restored, sales order history intact, happy developer.

I'd still like to hear your solutions/thoughts though!

Comment: Glad you had a backup! Question: did the sales order history only appear when you set their id back, or did this data import/export with them automagically?

Comment: The sales order history only appeared _after_ updating the ID to the old one.